# C# find and replace

Tags: c#, string

I have a string variable of type `////abc/abc/abc/asd.aspx` .

There can be any number of `/` at the begining of a string, i want the output to be  `/abc/abc/abc/asd.aspx` .

There can also be a string value as `/abc/abc/abc/asd.aspx` whose output should emain as `/abc/abc/abc/asd.aspx`

Kindly help, how do i use `String.Replace();` or any other method i can use?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How would you use `String.Replace()`? Did you read the manual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var correctedString = "/" + originalString.TrimStart('/');
```

Or you van do it via RegEx if there are any number of `/` in any part of string:

```
var correctedString = Regex.Replace(originalString, "/{2,}", "/");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = " ////abc/abc/abc/asd.aspx";
string newStr = "/"  + string.Join("/", str.Split(new[] { "/" }, 
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

This would work for string like `"///abc///abc//abc/asd.aspx"` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions:

```
string path = "////abc/abc/abc/asd.aspx";

path = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(path, @"/+", "/");
```

Result:

```
/abc/abc/abc/asd.aspx
```